# What does “Network cable unplugged” icon *really* mean?

Tags: windows-7, ethernet, network-adapter

I thought that the "Network cable unplugged" icon did mean link-down. But, I see a funny behavior on Windows-7, "Network cable unplugged" icon with "Unidentified network" on a *linked-up* interface.

Pictures here: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/63218/32547

Do you have a detailed information what the icon with red "X" means? Obviously, it does not mean the same as "Network cable unplugged"...

Comment: Not rare situation... it seems OS (the procedure which must to alter the icon) simply loose state change event, or it is some icons cache issue. Sometimes window close-reopen helps, sometimes no, F5 helps never (at least I have no seen), disable/enable interface helps always.

Comment: I had to mention in the question: I see this behavior only with a certain USB-Ethernet adapter. Same Model/Chip another adapter works okay. That's why, it looked like a HW issue to me and I wanted to understand the potential problem.

Comment: It means no internet connectivity for whatever reason, icons are generic in nature.